# Getting "not a git repository" when tying to run "az acr build"

Tags: git, azure, docker, azure-container-registry

I've been studying Azure Container Registry and I'm using Microsoft's documentation. Right now I'm trying to follow theses steps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/publish-container-image-to-azure-container-registry/6-build-run-image-azure-container-registry

But when I try to run my command: `az acr build --image sample/hello-world:v1 --verbose --registry az204acrcarol --resource-group az204-acr-rg --verbose .` I keep getting:

> Output from dependency scanning: fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
> Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).

I am absolutely sure that I am in a git repository, which is https://github.com/aclimarin/az204. When I run `git status` in the same directory I get:

> On branch main \ Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

---

See the print below:

[image]

---

This is the content of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/hello-world
```

---

I already tried to specify the repository URL with the command:

```
az acr build --image sample/hello-world:v1 --registry az204acrcarol --resource-group az204-acr-rg --file Dockerfile --build-arg BUILD_CONTEXT=https://github.com/aclimarin/az204.git .
```

I also tried to add `--no-push` flag

Comment: Why are you specifying the resource-group on the build command?

Comment: Because if i don't it will try some random resource group that doesn't exist

Comment: I managed to solve it! I was on windows, so I decided to use my ubuntu vm, and it worked. I didn't even need to create a git repository.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly we see this type of error because of the in-correct root directory of your project where the `.git` folder is located.

- I have tried the same approach getting application from git to ACR and able to run the application successfully.

Here the application in Git repository.

[image]

[image]

Created ACR in portal and Enabled user Admin [login](https://i.imgur.com/t9vkEdB.png).

[image]

I have used this following command to build t

```
az acr build --registry <your_acr_name> --file Dockerfile --platform windows https://github.com/SureshChikkam-MT/testpyapp.git
```

Here I able to build in acr and the application is running successfully.

**In Azure CLI:**

[image]

Comment: I did that. In my print there's a ```git status```command

Comment: I was able to run the command using my ubuntu vm without even creating a git repository or having to specify the resource group

Comment: I was just trying to say that I've already tried what you mentioned, and that it's explicit in the question. I didn't mean to offend.